# COMMAND TASK Limitation in Power Center

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement that if we have a bad file generated through a session and if its not a 0 byte file, I need to send an alert mail to Operations team.

I have the flow as below:

```
Session -> Command task
```

Command task has the below command

```
if [ -s $INFA_ROOT/BadFiles/<filename_<wf_date>.bad>]; then echo "reject | mailx -s "test" abc@abc.com fi
```

Command task executes successfully but workflow log says that command task failed with

> error code 256

Same command if i run in UNIX it triggers the mail.

Do we have any limitation in using command task

Thanks

Comment: Are you using an OS profile?

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz Yes, $INFA_ROOT is defined. Issue was a due to a semicolon which was missed in the command

Comment: @Maciejg: Yes. Issue was due to a semicolon which was missed in the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved by adding `;` as below,

Previous:

```
if [ -s $INFA_ROOT/BadFiles/<filename_<wf_date>.bad>]; then echo "reject | mailx -s "test" abc@abc.com fi
```

Modified:

```
if [ -s $INFA_ROOT/BadFiles/<filename_<wf_date>.bad>]; then echo "reject | mailx -s "test" abc@abc.com ; fi
```

Note the semicolon between `abc@abc.com` and `fi`.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note: if your Unix script exits with error code 1, Informatica command task errors out with the error code 256. Took some time to decrypt this.